# Python AttributeError:- Main instance has no attribute 'placeName'

Tags: python, class, module

```
class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        def placeName(self):
            place_name = raw_input("\n=> Enter a place name: ")
            placename_data = place_name.strip()
            if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]*$", placename_data):
                return placename_data
            else:
                print("Error! Only Alphabets from are allowed as input!")
a = Main()
new = a.placeName()
```

Above code for placeName() method runs correctly without using class but when I try to add it in a class, code gives an attribute error . Can't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: If you want to define a method in your `Main` class, don't define it _inside_ `__init__`. For this example, you can remove `def __init__(self):` entirely.

Comment: @Khelwood: After removing init I am getting this error <TypeError: placeName() takes no arguments (1 given)">

Comment: That's a different error produced by something not shown in the code you have posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define `__init__` inside the Main class.

```
class Main():
    def placeName(self):
        place_name = raw_input("\n=> Enter a place name: ")
        placename_data = place_name.strip()
        if re.match("^[a-zA-Z]*$", placename_data):
            return placename_data
        else:
            print("Error! Only Alphabets from are allowed as input!")
a = Main()
new = a.placeName()
```

Please remove `__init__` method and try.

Comment: class  Main():
      def placeName():
      place_name = raw_input("\n=> Enter a place name: ")
      print(place_name)
    a = Main()
    b = a.placeName()

Comment: Sorry I tried removing init and also tried with simplest code but it comes a type error <TypeError: placeName() takes no arguments (1 given)>

Comment: you forgot 'self' in function

Comment: Hey! Thanks, it works now. Sorry I am a beginner to classes. I have a question, why did we required self here? I had the understanding of using it in init method only.

Comment: In python for every method within a class required self, you can refer it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the help :)